# Problems loading bitmap data into an OpenGL texture

Tags: c++, opengl, bmp

Unfortunatly, I have some problems with glBindTexture().

When I try to bind a bitmap image to my skybox I only see some white. I tested it with other figures and also that does not work. I am sure the problem is in the Engine class.

This is my engine.cpp, here I load the bitmap et cetra:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>

#include <iostream>
#include "engine.h"

unsigned char* Engine::getImageContents(char path[], BITMAPINFOHEADER* bih) {
    FILE* input; fopen_s(&input, path, "rb");

    if (input != NULL) {
        BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
        fread(&bfh, sizeof(bfh), 1, input);
        fread(&bih, sizeof(bih), 1, input);

        unsigned char* data =
            new unsigned char[bih->biWidth * bih->biHeight * bih->biBitCount / 8];

        fread(data, sizeof(data), 1, input);
        fclose(input);

        return data;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

void Engine::bindTexture(char path[]) {
    this->bindTexture(this->getTextureId(path));
}

void Engine::bindTexture(unsigned int id) {
    if (id != this->boundTexture) {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
        this->boundTexture = id;
    }
}

unsigned int Engine::getTextureId(char path[]) {
    if (this->textureMap.find(path) != this->textureMap.end()) {
        return this->textureMap[path];
    } else {
        unsigned int id; glGenTextures(1, &id);
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
        unsigned char* data = this->getImageContents(path, &bih);
        this->setupTexture(data, id, bih.biWidth, bih.biHeight);
        this->textureMap.insert(std::pair<char*, unsigned int>(path, id));
        return id;
    }
}

void Engine::setupTexture(unsigned char* data, unsigned int id, long width, long height) {
    this->setupTexture(data, id, width, height, false);
}

void Engine::setupTexture(unsigned char* data, unsigned int id, long width, long height, bool clamp) {
    std::cout << height << std::endl;
    this->bindTexture(id);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, clamp ? GL_CLAMP : GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, clamp ? GL_CLAMP : GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data);
}
```

I use the class like this:

```
Engine::bindTexture(path);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the type of the image is `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` and not `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` ?

Comment: Also shouldn't you do `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` before `glBindTexture` ? OpenGL has 8 texture "slots".

Comment: @rwols I changed GL_UNSIGNED_INT to GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE without success, and glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) is not found.

Comment: Are you using shaders? If so, what does your fragment shader look like?

Comment: @rwols Nope, I do not :)

Comment: Is `Engine::setupTexture()` called with a current GL context?

Comment: *"Also shouldn't you do `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` before `glBindTexture`?"* - No, you should not (or need not) if you're not caring about multi-texturing at all (which the OP probably doesn't, since he seems to use OpenGL 1.1 without an extension loading library, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few possible problems.

1. Are you sure you load not compressed .bmp file, please check bfh.biCompression
2. You can use GL_RGBA if bih->biBitCount == 32, try to use GL_RGB
3. Try to use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE instead of GL_UNSIGNED_INT
4. Please check image size, I think for skybox it should be something like 128x128, 256x256, 512x512, i.e. power-of-2 texture size
5. Replace 
    fread(data, sizeof(data), 1, input); 
   on 
   fread(data, 1, bih->biWidth * bih->biHeight * bih->biBitCount / 8, input);

Comment: I forgot to say, when I get bih.biWidth of BITMAPINFOHEADER it returns a random value. And number 3 I already did. Also I changed GL_RGBA to GL_RGB

Comment: please change fread(&bih, sizeof(bih), 1, input); 
on
fread(&bih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, input);  
bih is pointer

Comment: @VladislavLitunovsky: No, you're still passing the address of a pointer, which will trash the stack.  See my answer for the correct call.

Comment: @RandomUser Please take a look at this [link](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/how-to-load-a-bitmap-r1966). It explains how to load .bmp and some issues.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't right:

```
fread(&bih, sizeof(bih), 1, input);
```

`bih` is already a pointer to the structure.  You want:

```
fread(bih, sizeof *bih, 1, input);
```

In addition, you really should use `bfOffBits` from the `BITMAPFILEHEADER`, and not assume the bitmap bits immediately follow a `BITMAPINFOHEADER`.  See [the MSDN topic describing the format of bitmap files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183391.aspx).

Comment: Ah, the ol' `sizeof(pointer)`-while-I-actually-meant-`sizeof(theByteArray)` trap

Comment: @rwols: The address to store the data was also wrong.  The size *does* match the buffer -- but they're both wrong.

Comment: I do not think this is a problem, it changed nothing.

Comment: @RandomUser Just because it didn't solve *all* of your errors doesn't mean it actually wasn't *an* error.